# ag-grid node.setData(newData) does not execute getNodeChildDetails

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

When setting new data on a row node, the getNodeChildDetails is not being called.

We are trying to lazy load a tree data structure by first providing a dummy child row and later, when the row is expanded, we load the children via http and then reset the parent row data, hoping the children replaced and loaded, but getNodeChildDetails in not called.

Pseudocode of our grid options is as follows:

```
onRowGroupOpened: function (event) {
  var node = event.node
  var api = this.api
  if (node.allLeafChildren[0].data.__loadingFacade) {
    loadChildrenFn(node.data).then(function (children) {
      var newData = angular.extend(
        {}, node.data, { __children: children }
      );
      node.setData(newData);
    });
  }
},

getNodeChildDetails: function (rowItem) {
  if (rowItem.__loadingFacade) {
    return null
  }
  return {
    group: true,
    children: rowItem.__children || [{ __loadingFacade: 1 }],
    key: rowItem.row_id
 };
```

}

Comment: I'm having the same basic problem (using child nodes but not grouping). 
 Which ag-grid version are you on?  They've had new releases almost monthly lately, with some large changes.  My code worked in version 10, but I tried upgrading to 13.1 and getNodeChildDetails is not called after the row is updated, even though other changes to the rowData are correctly refreshed in the grid.